# Voice controlled robot

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, atmega, robotics, matlab

1. Suggest me book name or link to study for voice controlled robot (DSP on matlab for voice recognition).
2. What is the hardware module/ sensor for voice recongnition?

Comment: This site is intended for specific design questions. Asking how to realize a complete project without providing any ideas of your own is discouraged.

Comment: I wouldn't normally offer advice on such an inappropriate question, but it could save you from picking the wrong avenue to start down:  There is no way you're going to get successful *voice recognition* using an ATmega16. It only has 16K of program memory for a start, and zero DSP functions (save for an ADC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.How I can make voice controlled robot?

Maybe there are ready-made solutions, but voice controlled robot require concept like this

> Microphone -> ADC conversion -> Frequency domain voice analysis (DSP)
>   -> Logic based on results from DSP which controls robot

2.Give me some idea to start this project?

See 1)

3.Which hardware module/sensor we can use for voice recognition?

See 2)